# Domain for a char with only 5 digits. Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a domain in PostgreSQL for the insert of a code of only 5 digits (from 00000 to 99999). I want to keep all 0 before(int deletes 0 before other numbers) so that I  can insert values like 00001.

Answer (score 0):

Do a padding by the left of your numeric value that must be stored in a varchar field

```
select lpad(1::text,5,'0');
```